# Making a grouped bar chart using a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, bar-chart

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart using numeric type data in the form of a matrix. The data frame I am pulling from has the data stored as strings so I also need to transform the data to the numeric type.

## making vectors

> wt250 <- c(as.numeric(df$WT.250[which(df$X=="Ifng")]), as.numeric(df$WT.250[which(df$X=="Prdm1")]), as.numeric(df$WT.250[which(df$X=="Il2ra")]), as.numeric(df$WT.250[which(df$X=="Cd69")])
> wt50 <- c(as.numeric(df$WT.50[which(df$X=="Ifng")]), as.numeric(df$WT.50[which(df$X=="Prdm1")]), as.numeric(df$WT.50[which(df$X=="Il2ra")]), as.numeric(df$WT.50[which(df$X=="Cd69")]))
> wt10 <- c(as.numeric(df$WT.10[which(df$X=="Ifng")]), as.numeric(df$WT.10[which(df$X=="Prdm1")]), as.numeric(df$WT.10[which(df$X=="Il2ra")]), as.numeric(df$WT.10[which(df$X=="Cd69")])

## making the matrix

> m <- matrix(c(wt250, wt50, wt10), nrow=3, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)

## vectors for details of the bar plot

> names <- c("WT-250", "WT-50", "WT-10")
> colors <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green")

## graphing the bar plot

> barplot(m, main = "Genes", ylab = "Concentration", names.arg = names, col = colors, beside = TRUE)

I expect a grouped bar chart (multiple bars that are adjacent to each other) with WT-250, WT-50, and WT-10 on the x axis which 4 bars each in the colors red, orange, yellow, and green.
Instead, I get the following error message:
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick fix replace your matrix creation:

```
m <- matrix(c(wt250, wt50, wt10), nrow=3, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)
```

by

```
m <- matrix(c(wt250, wt50, wt10), nrow=4, ncol=3)
```

So that you now have your vectors in columns.

Instead of "names" use "colnames".
Then your code should work, and barplot will be able to plot what you want.

Example :

```
mat <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:3]
rownames(mat) <- letters[23:26]

barplot(mat,col = c("red", "blue", "cyan", "orange"), beside = TRUE)
```

[image: Grouped_bar_chart]